# Reopen activity and the activity doesn't call oncreate

Tags: android

Here is my problem : I started one activity to select date, after choosing i call finish() to close the activity . next step i reopen the same activity ,i found the activity didn't call oncreate method. Is there anyone can tell me why?

**here is the activity in manifest file and the style.**

```
<activity android:name=".activity.CalendarViewActivity"
      android:theme="@style/calendarview_activity"/>

<style name="calendarview_activity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/calendarview_act_bg</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_toolbar_title</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**here is the activity code**

```
public class CalendarViewActivity extends BaseActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, OnDateSelectedListener, OnMonthChangedListener {
    private MaterialCalendarView mMaterialCV;
    DatabaseReference mTimesheetDailyStatusRef;
    private CalendarDay mMonthDate;
    private TextView tvYear;
    private TextView tvDay;
    private static final int SUBMITTED = 2;
    private static final int UN_SUBMITTED = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_CODE = 200;
    private ValueEventListener mStatusListener;
    private DatabaseReference statusRootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_calendarview_activity);
        initView();
        initData();
    }

    private void initData() {
        statusRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants
                .COLLECTION_ENGINEER_ROOT).child(Constants.COLLECTION_TIMESHEETS_STATUS).child
                (getUid());
        mTimesheetDailyStatusRef = statusRootRef
                .child(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                .child(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)));
        CalendarDay calendarDay = CalendarDay.from(Calendar.getInstance());
        setStatus(calendarDay);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setSize();
        mMaterialCV = (MaterialCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarview_timesheet);
        mMaterialCV.setWeekDayTextAppearance(getResColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        mMaterialCV.setHeaderTextAppearance(getResColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        mMaterialCV.setOnDateChangedListener(this);
        mMaterialCV.setOnMonthChangedListener(this);
        mMaterialCV.setCurrentDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mMonthDate = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.KEY_SELECTED_DATE);
        if (mMonthDate != null) {
            mMaterialCV.setSelectedDate(mMonthDate);
            mMaterialCV.setCurrentDate(mMonthDate);
        } else {
            setCurrentDate();
        }
        tvDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarview_day);
        tvYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarview_year);
        setSelectDataToTop(mMonthDate);
        TextView tvOK = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose_day_ok);
        TextView tvCancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose_day_cancel);
        tvCancel.setTypeface(fontMedium);
        tvOK.setTypeface(fontMedium);
        tvCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvOK.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setCurrentDate() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mMonthDate = CalendarDay.from(c);
    }

    private void setSize() {
        WindowManager m = getWindowManager();
        Display d = m.getDefaultDisplay();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getWindow().getAttributes();
        p.height = (int) (d.getHeight() * 0.85);
        p.width = (int) (d.getWidth() * 0.9);
        p.alpha = 1.0f;
        p.dimAmount = 0.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(p);
        getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.choose_day_cancel:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.choose_day_ok:
                Intent backIntent = new Intent();
                backIntent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_SELECTED_DATE, mMonthDate);
                setResult(RESULT_CODE, backIntent);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setSelectDataToTop(CalendarDay mMonthDate) {
        tvYear.setText(String.valueOf(mMonthDate.getYear()));
        int dayOfWeek = mMonthDate.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String monthAndDay = TimeFormatUtil.getDate(mMonthDate.getCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
        tvDay.setText(TimeFormatUtil.getWeekSimple(dayOfWeek) + ", " + monthAndDay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date,
                               boolean selected) {
        mMonthDate = date;
        setSelectDataToTop(date);
        mMaterialCV.invalidateDecorators();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
        mTimesheetDailyStatusRef.removeEventListener(mStatusListener);
        mTimesheetDailyStatusRef = null;
        mStatusListener = null;
        mMonthDate = date;
        setStatus(mMonthDate);
    }

    private void setStatus(final CalendarDay calendarDay) {
        mTimesheetDailyStatusRef = statusRootRef.child(String.valueOf(calendarDay.getYear())).child
                (String.valueOf(calendarDay.getMonth()));
        mStatusListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<CalendarStatusDay> days = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CalendarStatusDay day = child.getValue(CalendarStatusDay.class);
                    days.add(day);
                }
                if (isFinishing()) {
                    return;
                }
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                ArrayList<CalendarDay> unSubmittedDays = new ArrayList<>();
                unSubmittedDays.clear();
                ArrayList<CalendarDay> submittedDays = new ArrayList<>();
                submittedDays.clear();
                for (CalendarStatusDay day : days) {
                    if (day.getStatus() == SUBMITTED) {
                        calendar.set(calendarDay.getYear(), calendarDay.getMonth(),
                                day.getDayOfmonth());
                        submittedDays.add(CalendarDay.from(calendar));
                    } else if (day.getStatus() == UN_SUBMITTED) {
                        calendar.set(calendarDay.getYear(), calendarDay.getMonth(),
                                day.getDayOfmonth());
                        unSubmittedDays.add(CalendarDay.from(calendar));
                    }
                }
                mMaterialCV.addDecorators(
                        new EventDecorator(getDrawable(R.drawable.submitted_selector),
                                submittedDays));
                mMaterialCV.addDecorator(
                        new EventDecorator(getDrawable(R.drawable.unsubmitted_selector),
                                unSubmittedDays));
                mMaterialCV.addDecorators();
                unSubmittedDays.clear();
                unSubmittedDays = null;
                submittedDays.clear();
                submittedDays = null;
                days.clear();
                days = null;

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mTimesheetDailyStatusRef.addValueEventListener(mStatusListener);
    }

}
```

Comment: onCreate() gets called only the first time the activity is created unless it gets destroyed for lack of resources, in your case the next time you go to the finished activity it will call onResume()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  `startActivityForResult` to get SELECTED DATE then you need to Override  `onActivityResult` method in your `Actvity`.Because when you `setResult` like below code control goes to `onActivityResult` method in previous `Actvity`.

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent();
backIntent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_SELECTED_DATE, mMonthDate);
setResult(RESULT_CODE, backIntent);
finish();
```

Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity

```
 @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
     // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
        if(requestCode==2)  
        {  
         String selcted_date=data.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_SELECTED_DATE);   
         textView1.setText(message);  
         }  
     }
```

Comment: of course i override the method you mentioned, i don't think it's the reason.

Comment: @ so have you used any lounchMode in AndoridManifest.xml file.

Comment: sorry it's my bad, now i know the oncreate method was been called after the callback method which cause my app crash.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the activity was already running in the background. if getting an action callback is all you look for you can use the `startActivityForResult` method and get a callback in the `onActivityResult` of the calling activity.

and if you really want to open a new instance of the same activity then look for the `launchMode` parameter and add it to activity tag in manifest refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: how does the activity running in the background ? i called finish(),  is there any way to destroy it thoroughly?